# Multi packages workspace under WinROS

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, windows, winros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys,
I have a Hydro winros workspace containing three packages that are dependent.
The first one is a messages and services definition package called ros_msgs.
The second package contains several C++ abstract classes and depends on ros_msgs. It's called ros_radar.
The last one contains implementation classes and thus depend on ros_radar and transitively on ros_msgs.

My problem is that when I call *winros_make*, it fails after building DLLs with the following message:
**NMAKE: fatal error U1073: Unable to find 'D:\Projects\Ros_project\overlay\devel\lib\ros_radar.lib**

In fact, my *devel* folder only contains DLL for ros_radar.
Is there a special configuration parameter I forgot to use ?

As a note, the first two packages are already used under Ubuntu without any problems.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233086/multi-packages-workspace-under-winros/) by [Fred Praca](https://answers.ros.org/users/26720/fred-praca/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-04-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, after struggling for days on this topic, I think I found the solution.
This problem is related to lib generation inside CMake for Windows DLL which is something weird for a Linux developer :)
In the second package *CMakeLists.txt*, I just added  the following

```
set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS TRUE)
```

This way, CMake generated both *lib* and *defs* files for my classes.
I was expecting a special *catkin* directive but I had to look on CMake side.

I hope this will help someone else.

---

Originally posted by [Fred Praca](https://answers.ros.org/users/26720/fred-praca/) with karma: 16 on 2016-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0